# Jquery Hide/Show multiple division by single classname

Tags: jquery, html

HTML

```
  <p class="heading"></p>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">content1</div>
 <p class="heading"></p>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">content2</div>
 <p class="heading"></p>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">content3</div>
 <p class="heading"></p>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">content4</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
              jQuery(".targetDiv").hide();
              //toggle the componenet 
              jQuery(".heading").click(function()
              {
                jQuery(this).next(".targetDiv").slideToggle(500);

              });
            });
    </script>
```

here i'm able to show one div on clicking heading but when i'm going to open another it must get hidden. Infact while i'm opening one div other must get hidden.

pls help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
              jQuery(".targetDiv").hide();
              //toggle the componenet 
              jQuery(".heading").click(function()
              {
                jQuery(".targetDiv").slideUp();
                jQuery(this).next(".targetDiv").slideToggle(500);

              });
            });
</script>
```

A small explanation: It first hides all divs and then opens one. I should do so fast that you won't be able to see it.

Comment: I've changed it to make it slide up in place of hiding directly. I should make it a bit prettier.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".heading").click(function() {                        
    $('.targetDiv:visible').hide();  /* reference to the single previous
                                      *  opened tab and hide it 
                                      */
    $(this).next(".targetDiv").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Et4gh/1/

Just add the jQuery(".targetDiv").hide(); into the click function too.